# Untouchable disks via Disk Utility and GParted

Tags: linux, macos, hard-drive, partitioning

I have what I think are hybrid GUID/MBR disks that I created by splitting already MBR/NTFS disks via GParted, leaving unallocated space, then creating HFS partitions within OS X from the unallocated space on them.

I want to delete those HFS partitions and re-extend the NTFS on them, but I can't because GParted sees the disk as somehow unchangeable; I assume OS X has done something to them.

I now can't extend or do anything to the disks via the OS X Disk Utility OR GParted. What can I do?

Comment: "somehow unchangeable" isn't going to help people.  [Show the actual error message](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a different utility. Either disk management in windows, or programs like partition management, adobe disk director, etc. I feel confident about the last one, as it has many features, but since the problem seems a tad ill defined, the others may work as well.

Comment: thanks. and i did read something about using a utility within windows, but i deleted the other two partitions that I created which had Fedora and Windows installed on them because I no longer have any use for them. os x is now my only os

Comment: can i somehow achieve this with the windows disk using some kind of force command in bash?